# Magento is redirecting to cart when continuing from Billing info

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Whenever I add an item to the cart, then checkout, I choose register or checkout as guest. Then I enter the billing information and click continue. It always redirects back to the cart. I have not been able to figure out why.

Example is here: http://38.98.53.62

Thanks

Comment: This is the error I am getting:a:5:{i:0;s:88:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ca.sort_order' in 'order clause'";i:1;s:2476:"#0 /var/www/specopsbrand/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300):

Comment: I should also add I was using 1.4.1 and just upgraded to 1.4.2

Comment: It turns out, I needed to run this sql: UPDATE `eav_entity_type` SET `attribute_model` = 'customer/attribute', `additional_attribute_table` = 'customer/eav_attribute', `entity_attribute_collection` = 'customer/attribute_collection' WHERE `eav_entity_type`.`entity_type_code` = 'customer';

Comment: here is the reference: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/%3Cbr%3E%3Cdiv%20class=comment_name%3E%28Asertwiwu%29%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%20class=phot_comment2%3EEfwpogjfhdfd%20hayeuwio%20djhdh%20%3Ca%20href=/viewthread/214185/#t288848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for posting the address, it makes it a lot easier to see.

On clicking continue there is an AJAX request which comes back with an error. The checkout javascript jumps back to a predetermined `failureUrl` on a server error which is what you are seeing. The error message will most likely be stored in `var/report` so go look at the most recent file there and see what the problem is. Update your question with it if you're still stuck.

**P.S.**
You have the following in your theme:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery.noConflict();
```

The first of the two lines causes an error and is superfluous anyway, it is not related to the checkout problem but it doesn't do to tempt fate.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you, basically have mcrypt installed. Apparently it’s needed for the password encryption to function. And when it doesn’t, the logic flow gets confused.

Use the Magento check php to see if your server has all the software,

Comment: What are you saying the answer is?