# Magento - Registration problem - User is sent to My Cart after entering billing information

Tags: magento

When a user goes to checkout for their items, they are given the option to register. If that option is chosen, they proceed to enter their information. After entering their Billing Information and clicking Continue, they are sent back to the My Cart page and the registration process never completes. I attempted the fix located at the following SO question: [Magento is redirecting to cart when continuing from Billing info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844192/magento-is-redirecting-to-cart-when-continuing-from-billing-info) - but it did not work.

Background info - I'm using a template designed for 1.4.x with Magento 1.5.0.1 stable. Here is the URL for my site:

http://allyourga.me

EDIT1: *Errors deleted because they were unrelated*

EDIT 2: This issue may be related to another one I'm having: [Magento - Registration error - 1054 Unknown column 'ca.sort_order' in 'order clause'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712762/magento-registration-error-1054-unknown-column-ca-sort-order-in-order-clau)

Error logs from that question have been relisted below:

```
2011-04-19T23:04:43+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index:  HTTP_USER_AGENT  in /home/user/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/theme100/template/page/ie/ie6.phtml on line 2
2011-04-19T23:04:43+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index:  HTTP_USER_AGENT  in /home/user/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/theme100/template/page/ie/ie6.phtml on line 3
2011-04-19T23:04:43+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index:  HTTP_USER_AGENT  in /home/user/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/theme100/template/page/ie/ie6.phtml on line 19
2011-04-19T23:04:43+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index:  HTTP_USER_AGENT  in /home/user/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/theme100/template/page/ie/ie6.phtml on line 20
```

Lines 2, 3, 19, 20 from ie6.phhtml have been reproduced below:

```
2 if(eregi("opera",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) echo "<b></b>"; 
3 else if(eregi("MSIE 6.0",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) echo "

19 else if(eregi("Mozilla.[4.]",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) echo "<b></b>"; 
20 else if(eregi("Mozilla.[5|6]",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) echo "<b></b>";
```

EDIT 3: The errors posted from EDIT 2 are the ones that are related to this problem.

Comment: Do you have logging enabled? What errors (if any) are recorded in your error log? What JS response is given to the AJAX call just before you redirect?

Comment: Error log has been added to original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a seriously defective database. I suspect the problem might have arisen either when uploading sample data from a purchased Magento template or when I was migrating my website from one server to a new one.

I fixed it by running Magento's database repair tool which can be found at the following link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

The errors that popped up were a lot of `Added missing foreign key(s)` and two `Added missing fields`. For a full report on the errors that popped up, go to the following Stack Overflow question:

[Magento - Database repair tool - Added missing foreign keys problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761298/magento-database-repair-tool-added-missing-foreign-keys-problems)

Answer (score 1):

The error in your log points to an issue with your actual Paypal integration. My first guess here would be that you entered incorrect/incomplete details for the Paypal configuration.

In fact, [Paypal says](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_errorcodes):

> This error can be caused by an
>   incorrect API username, an incorrect
>   API password, or an invalid API
>   signature. Make sure that all three of
>   these values are correct. For your
>   security, PayPal does not report
>   exactly which of these three values
>   might be in error

Check your credentials and try again. Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe
.

Comment: I did notice that. Turns out my API credentials weren't even entered, so I fixed that and made sure that it was correct. Unfortunately that did not solve the issue. In addition, whenever I try to register again, the problem persists, yet no new errors are added to my logs. The API credentials seemingly solved the problem pointed out in the logs, but I guess the errors in the logs are unrelated to my issue.

Comment: As updated in the original question, it turns out the second set of errors are being generated every time I try to register a new account through the checkout process.

Comment: The second error doesn't seem terribly related either. Try checking the JS response from the AJAX calls running on the checkout page. One of them may point to where things are going wrong.

Comment: Use Firebug's net tab to snoop on the AJAX parameters and responses coming from Magento. You may need to be clever about denying Magento's attempt to redirect with an Esc after the AJAX but before the redirect. This, though, should give you an idea of what Magento is trying to do.

Comment: `POST saveBilling` failed with status 503 Service Unavailable. Subsequently `GET cart` was aborted. The error report that is produced gives me `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ca.sort_order' in 'order clause'";i:1;s:2425:"` - The same error that is produced when I try to create a new account via the Log In link. The log is almost exactly the same as in the other question I've linked to.

Comment: Okay, throwing that exception could definitely cause the redirect. Solving the sort_order issue is your best bet at this juncture.

Comment: I'll investigate further. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Although its old post but i want to share my experience.
i was also facing this issue and then in net tab of firebug when i click continue after giving the billing information, there was 500 error.
more investigation into the error log of magento shows its actually php-mcrypt was missing on vps. 
and i just installed n its working fine now. may this info help someone.